# When I request authentication from the Google Drive API to allow access it loads the disabled buttons

Tags: delphi, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am using the OAuth2Authenticator component to generate the API Access Token, I have always used the following Authorization-Endpoint setting: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth', Token-Endpoint: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/token', Redirection-Endpoint:'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto', Response-Type:'code'e Access-Scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', when I request Authorization it loads a window to enter username and password and displays options to allow and deny, but these buttons are coming off. Has [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYc37.png)anyone ever experienced this?

Comment: What does anything you've written above have to do with Delphi?

Comment: Make sure that JavaScript is enabled. JavaScript is used to enable these buttons, which are disabled on render. Also, have you noticed this behaviour in other APIs or just in Drive API?

Comment: I'm sorry, because I tagged the delphi tag, at first I am a little layman on this subject and how I did the delphi update recently just coincided with the problem. I thought it was something related to the component.
The problem was related to how information was displayed in the browser. How do I use Tfrm_OAuthWebForm to display the authorization window and it uses the TWebBrowser component to load the generated link. And TWebBroser was running on an older version of Internet Explorer, I upgraded it to a newer version and the issue was fixed.